IntelliJ Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:
after 2 days I still haven't been able to solve the error. This is how I set up the project, but the error is still there. I've read many guides around to solve it, but the situation is always the same.I attach the images of the IntelliJ settings
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: frames/Enable has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 63.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0

1
2
3
4

I have never used IntelliJ with Java, but let's try to solve your issue .

this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0


Check your Windows' PATH variable if it contains old Java executables and remove them.
Check if on your system is installed latest JDK Development Kit, at the moment the latest is JDK 23, if contains old ones, not compatible with the latest version, just remove them.


Now i get this error:
`Your build is currently configured to use incompatible Java 23.0.1 and Gradle 8.8. Cannot sync the project.
The maximum compatible Gradle JVM version is 22.`

your solution doesn't work

Try to install compatible 22 version of Gradle then.

Already done and I don't understand why it's always the same exception. Even though I uninstalled version 8
